# Batchnormalize, Dropout and number of layers

Tags: tensorflow, activation, dropout

I'm learning batchnormalisation and dropout.  Saw this https://www.kaggle.com/ryanholbrook/dropout-and-batch-normalization.

The model

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_shape=[11]),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(1),
])
```

My question is do we put dropout before batchnormalization (BN) or after ?  Same results ?

My understand is that dropout will "deactivate" the neuron in the next layer (pardon my terminology).  So if I put before BN, would the BN be normalising incorrectly since it's not the full output from the previous layer.

So we should put dropout after BN ?  Does it matter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a closer look at the tensorflow [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout) regarding the dropout layer, you see it says:

> The Dropout layer randomly sets input units to 0 with a frequency of
> rate at each step during training time, which helps prevent
> overfitting. Inputs not set to 0 are scaled up by 1/(1 - rate) such
> that the sum over all inputs is unchanged.

This means dropout does not deactivate any neurons in the next layer but instead "deactivates" the inputs for the neurons (= the neurons receive a `0` as input). Note, this is often the case for practical Dropout, other frameworks such as [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout.html) use the same approach.

So BN after Dropout will not "normalize incorrectly" but instead do what it's programmed for, namely performing normalization, but now some inputs are having a 0 instead of their non-dropout value present.

Whether you put Dropout before or after BN depends on your data and can yield different results. Most of the time both techniques can be used for normalization and in my personal experience one of them suffices / they do not perform better combined. 
If you think of dropout as noise, putting Dropout before BN means you normalize a "noised" input, while putting it after means you add noise to the normalized data.

Comment: yes, I meant "deactivates" the inputs ... Thanks.

Comment: I can understand the noise part.  That's a good way to look at it.  However, shouldn't I BN all the output from the previous layer ?  If I only BN some of the values, won't the normalised values be incorrect since the calculation is done with a smaller set of values and will give rise to different mean and sd (if I don't look at it as noise).  Also, I've read the reason for using dropout, is that we want a (again excuse my terminology) "flexible model" so that the model is not fixed (ie more variety in designing the model).  Thanks...

Comment: All values from the previous layer get batch normalized. You are not doing the calculation on a smaller set of values but instead, always have the complete set of values, with dropout only changing some of the values to 0. 
For example:`[1,2,3]` -(dropout)-> `[1,0,3]` -(batch-norm, `mean=1.3`, `var=1.5`) -> `[(1-1.3)/1.5, (0-1.3)/1.5, (3-1.3)/1.5]`
Without Dropout the mean / var would be different (namely, `mean=2`, `var= 2/3`)

Comment: ic.  I initially thought that I should have the right mean/var but dropout some value.  If I put the dropout before, then the mean/var will change but if I put after, the mean/var will be for the previous layer.

Comment: Exactly @DataT!